# Why is my Recaptcha failing upon submission?

Tags: php, recaptcha

I spent a day getting Recaptcha to work on a site I created. We had to move the site to another hosting company recently. Now it constantly fails when the form is submitted.

I created a new set of keys and still nothing. I can't find any definitive support for this issue.

Could it be a PHP or server setting?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Even if it's just a way to get some data upon failure.

I'm using a demo form I found for testing purposes. It's the second demo I've tried and they both failed on submission.

**The Form**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google recapcha demo - Codeforgeek</title>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js' async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Google reCAPTHA Demo</h1>
   <form action="captcha-php.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="sender_name" placeholder="Your Name..."/>
    <input name="sender_email" placeholder="Your email..."/>
    <textarea placeholder="Your Message..." name="sender_message"></textarea>
        <div class="captcha_wrapper">
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdMl0saAAAAAI4PyxOt24481BPzmzTmiU2GGhR6"></div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="send_message">Send Message!</button>
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**captcha-php.php**

```
<?php
    $sender_name = stripslashes($_POST["sender_name"]);
    $sender_email = stripslashes($_POST["sender_email"]);
    $sender_message = stripslashes($_POST["sender_message"]);
    $response = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];

    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $data = array(
        'secret' => 'I have entered the secret key here',
        'response' => $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
    );
    $options = array(
        'http' => array (
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data)
        )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $verify = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    $captcha_success=json_decode($verify);

    if ($captcha_success->success==false) {
        echo "<p>You are a bot! Go away!</p>";
    } else if ($captcha_success->success==true) {
        echo "<p>You are not not a bot!</p>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: This might not be relevant, but I'm using Firefox with an adblocker, and recapcha doesn't work for me. This is not likely to be the same problem as you have, but your visitors might experience this and not bother to find a solution. There might be a good alternative to let your visitors prove they are not a robot. Have you tried [a honeypot](https://dev.to/felipperegazio/how-to-create-a-simple-honeypot-to-protect-your-web-forms-from-spammers--25n8)? Create your own, don't copy existing code!

Comment: Unfortunately, my client asked for Recaptha.

Comment: What fails? The script? The verification?

Comment: That's a good question. I thought it was the verification since I'm getting the "You are a bot!" text. But, when I check the stats of my Recaptcha account, It shows all passes and no fails.